# How to solve integration of natural log

Tags: integration

I am unsure on how to solve this integral

$$\displaystyle\int x\cdot\ln(x^2+3) ·x dx.$$

I thought of multiplying $x$ by $x$ in order to get $x²$ so that the equation would become $x²\ln(x^2+3)dx.$

However, I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Any help?

Comment: Please use mathjax to format your question as in its current state it is quite unclear .[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by $b$ ? and how would you get $x^2$ if you multiplied $x$ by $b$?

Comment: is this $\int x^2ln(x^2+3)dx$?

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: If i use u subsitution then i would get u=x²+3 and du=2xdx. dx=du/2x . The answer i get is ln (x+3) +c.

Comment: That substitution would be useless as you have $x^2$ not $x$ and would be left with a term of $x$ .

Comment: I get that 2xln(u) ·du/2x. I cancel out the 2x and i am left with ln(x²+3)+c.

Comment: My answer is wrong.  I figured that it is x². Should i use integration by parts?

Comment: The final edits i made show to exact problem . Wrote it badly beforre.

Comment: So your substitution works.

Comment: Nope.  I wrote 2x which would of cancelled out instead of x squared.

Comment: Are you sure about the question ? Strange that there are two $x$ factors.

Comment: Yes i am sure, it was a past exam question.

Comment: actually the question is a definite integral, tending from 1 -2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the $x$'s may be multiplied so that we have $x^2$.

One way ... integrate by parts
$$
\int \!{x}^{2}\ln  \left( {x}^{2}+3 \right) \,{\rm d}x=\frac{{x}^{3}
\ln  \left( {x}^{2}+3 \right)}{3} -\frac{2}{3}\,\int \!{\frac {{x}^{4}}{{x}^{2}+3}
}\,{\rm d}x
$$
This is how you get rid of the log.
Presumably  you know how to integrate a rational function.  With that denominator: your answer involves an arctangent (or else complex numbers).

**added**
$$
u = \log(x^2+3),\qquad du= \frac{2x \;dx}{x^2+3}
\\
dv=x^2\;dx,\qquad v = \frac{x^3}{3},
\\
uv = \frac{x^3\log(x^2+3)}{3}
\\
\int u\;dv = \int x^2 \log(x^2+3)dx
\\
\int v\;du = \int \frac{x^3}{3}\;\frac{2x \;dx}{x^2+3} = 
\frac{2}{3}\int \frac{x^4 \;dx}{x^2+3}
$$

Comment: u=x²+3  du=2xdx  dv=x²dx and v=x³/3.. Am i correct?

Comment: Unfortunately i am unable to understand how you got the second part , starting from 2/3.

Comment: start with $u=ln(x^2+3)$ then $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{2x}{x^2+3}$ similarly with $\frac{dv}{dx}=x^2$, then $v=x^3/3$

Comment: Thank you! I understood

Comment: The last part of the equation , in order to integrate it, i should use u subsitution right?

Comment: Integrating a rational function should be in your calculus text.  You would do long division, and in the end you have to integrate $1/(x^2+3)$ ... there, you make a trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of integrating the **rational function part only** in @GEdgar's solution we have I think (missing out constant of integration)

$$\int (a x^2-b) \; dx=\frac{ax^3}{3}-bx=\int \frac{(ax^2-b)(ax^2+b)}{ax^2+b} \; dx$$

which can be rearranged to give
$$a^2 \int \frac{x^4}{ax^2+b} \; dx=\frac{ax^3}{3}-bx+b^2\int \frac{1}{ax^2+b} \; dx$$

Since $a=1$ in this example we have
$$\int \frac{x^4}{x^2+b} \; dx=\frac{x^3}{3}-bx+b^2\int \frac{1}{x^2+b} \; dx$$

and since $\frac{d}{dx}$($\arctan(x/\sqrt{b}))=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{x^2+b}$

$$\int \frac{x^4}{x^2+b} \; dx=\frac{x^3}{3}-bx+\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{b}}\;\arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{b}})$$

Comment: Is this the wrong question you've answered?

Comment: @FrankW. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: Oh! My bad! $\phantom{}$

Comment: @FrankW. I now realise this has been raised as a separate question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811385/integration-functions